# Constructing a class to flatten python list

Tags: python, class, object

I want to construct a class to flatten a python list. I can make it by defining function like this;

```
liste=[[1,2],3,[4],[[5],6]]

flatLIST=[]

def recur(a):

    if (type(a)==list):
        for i in a:
           recur(i)
    else:
        flatLIST.append(a)

recur(liste)
flatLIST
```

> > [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

But when i cannot achieve it by constructing a class.

```
class flatYVZ():

    def __init__(self,liste):
        self.flatLIST=[]
        recur(liste)

    def recur(self,a):

        if (type(a)==list):
            for i in a:
                recur(i)
        else:
            self.flatLIST.append(a)

    def flatting(self):        
        self.sonuc=self.flatLIST

example=[[1,2],3,[4],[[5],6]]
objec=flatYVZ(example)
objec.sonuc
```

> > []

Comment: Er, `self.recur` ? Do you still have the global `recur` in scope?

Comment: When do you call `flatting`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference `self`, or you'll call the function you defined previously, not your class method.

Here you need to change `recur(liste)` to `self.recur(liste)` in `__init__` and `recur(i)` to `self.recur(i)` in `recur(self, a)`.

```
class flatYVZ():

    def __init__(self,liste):
        self.flatLIST=[]
        self.recur(liste)

    def recur(self,a):

        if (type(a)==list):
            for i in a:
                self.recur(i)
        else:
            self.flatLIST.append(a)

    def flatting(self):        
        self.sonuc=self.flatLIST

example=[[1,2],3,[4],[[5],6]]
objec=flatYVZ(example)
print(objec.flatLIST)
```